# html/template: "layout" is undefined

Tags: go, martini

I try to use martini framework with layout template:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/go-martini/martini"
    "github.com/martini-contrib/render"
)

func main() {
    m := martini.Classic()

    m.Use(render.Renderer(render.Options{Directory: "./templates",
        Layout:     "layout",
        Extensions: []string{".tmpl"},
    }))

    m.Get("/", func(r render.Render) {
        r.HTML(200, "mainPage", map[string]interface{}{"Title": "some title", "H1": "some h1"})
    })

    m.Run()
}
```

In the same folder as this `main.go`  file I got folder `templates` with `layout.tmpl` file:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></html>
<head></head>
<body>  
    <div id='left'>
        {{template "left" .}}
    </div>
    <div id='right'>
        {{template "right" .}}
    </div>
</body>
```

and `mainPage.tmpl` file:

```
{{define "left"}}
  left content
{{end}}

{{define "right"}}
    right content
{{end}}
```

When I open `http://localhost:3000/` in browser I see error:
`html/template: "layout" is undefined`

Comment: Haven't used martini, but it is a common issue to have templates fail at runtime due to you not being in the right directory when starting your app, have you tried to run from your main folder (parent of templates)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was that I run `go` file from random directory. To solve it I changed directory (`cd`) to parent of `templates` folder.

Answer (score -1):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></html>
   <head></head>
   <body>  
    <div id='left'>
        {{template "left" .}}
    </div>
    <div id='right'>
        {{template "right" .}}
    </div>
</body>
```

Make correct `html` close tag after `</body>`

That`s it:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head></head>
   <body>  
    <div id='left'>
        {{template "left" .}}
    </div>
    <div id='right'>
        {{template "right" .}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That typo didn't affect my error `“layout” is undefined`